# Текст накладывается друг на друга HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Суть всей проблемы в том, когда ширина браузера уменьшается до того размера, когда надпись не влезает в размеченную область, то вместо переноса на новую строку, он просто накладывается друг на друга. Данная ситуация повторяется и при принудительном переносе на новую строку тегом `<br>`.
**HTML**

```
<article class="back_coupling" id="contacts">
    <p class="title">
        <span class="number_title">03</span> Связь <br>со мной
    </p>
    <div class="form_feedback">
        <form class="feedback">
            <input class="data" type="text" placeholder="Имя" required/>
            <input class="data" type="text" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required/>
            <input class="subject" type="text" placeholder="Тема" required/>
            <textarea class="message" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea>
            <input title="Сообщение будет отправлено получателю" class="sub" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
            <div class="social">
                <picture>
                    <a href="#" title="Vkontakte"><img class="icon-social" src="/img/icons/icon-vk.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#" title="Skype"><img class="icon-social" src="/img/icons/icon-skype.png" /></a>
                    <a href="#" title="GitHub"><img class="icon-social" src="/img/icons/icon-github.png" /></a>
                </picture>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
     :root {
    --main_color: #C000CD;
    --main_color_light: #DB30E6;
    --main_cont: Montserrat-Regular;
    --main_title_color: silver;
    --margin_ability: 10px;
    --load_body: #444444;
    --padding_between_sections: 200px 0px 200px 0px;
}
.title {
        font-size: 48px;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        /*color: var(--main_title_color);*/
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 0px;
        transition: 1s;
        -o-transition: 1s;
        -moz-transition: 1s;
        -webkit-transition: 1s;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        white-space: normal;
    }    
    .back_coupling {
            background: url('/img/endfon.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #464646;
            padding: var(--padding_between_sections);
            z-index: 1;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 3px #323747 inset;
        }

        .form_feedback {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            padding: 50px 0px 0px;
        }

        .feedback {
            background-color: var(--main_title_color);
            padding: 50px;
            width: 480px;
            background-color: #4D5366;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #323747;
            border-radius: 15px;
            text-align: center
        }

        .feedback .data,
        .feedback .subject,
        .feedback .message {
            border: 0px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px 0px;
            width: 163px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        .feedback .subject,
        .feedback .message {
            width: 350px;
        }

        .feedback .message {
            height: 100px;
            font-family: var(--main_cont);
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        .feedback .sub {
            width: 372px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 40px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #323747;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px var(--main_color);
            border: 0px;
            transition: all ease 1s;
            -o-transition: all ease 1s;
            -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
            -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
            -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        .feedback .sub:hover {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px var(--main_color_light);
        }

        .feedback>input {
            display: flex;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у селектора `.title` `line-height: 0px;` стоит. Это из-за этого. Поставьте, например, `line-height: 1.2;`

Comment: Большое спасибо, совершенно об этом забыл)